# How do I search HTML formatted text in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2000  and I have 3 problems.

1. My web site saves some HTML formatted text into an `ntext` field.  How do I search this field?
2. I asked a question here before ([how to search from all field in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520102)), but I need to know which field the search result was found in.
3. I save some fields that use .NET encryption. How can I search this field? It is possible?

Comment: What sort of encryption? Do you have the key(s)?

Comment: i'm using .NET DESCryptoServiceProvider and CryptoStream classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE or [PATINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to search for a [wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx) expression within a ntext (or nvarchar(max)) column.

Answer (score 0):

My encryption is here>>

```
public string Encrypt(string strText, string strEncKey)
    {
        Byte[] byKey;
        Byte[] IV ={ 0x12, 0x34, 0x54, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };
        byKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strEncKey);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
    public string Decrypt(string strText, string strEncKey)
    {
        Byte[] byKey;
        Byte[] IV ={ 0x12, 0x34, 0x54, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };
        Byte[] inputByteArray;

        byKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strEncKey.Substring(0, 8));
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(strText);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

Using >>

```
Encrypt(value, "&%#@?,:*");
Decrypt(value, "&%#@?,:*");
```

Comment: What were you expecting anyone would do with this?

Comment: When i insert data to sql, i'm using this encryption. For example, i have table named tUser, tUser has 2 field named username and password. When i add new user, encrypt password field(for example before passoword='aaa', after encrypt password='FDSw>gF'). I need to select from this field in mssql

Comment: is it possible? Do you understand my problem?  
My english is bit of poor, sorry :(